# Should we have tags for series of questions?

Tags: discussion, policy, tags

@Patrick87 proposed the concept of heap automata ([here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/110/)) which has lead to three follow-up questions ([1](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/393/), [2](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/390/), [3](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/394/)) so far. It is not unlikely that more will follow.

Should we create a tag [heap-automata](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heap-automata) in this case? As far as I know, the concept is novel so there is no common association; the tag would only be used to string these questions together.

Answer (score 7):

As long as Patrick87 links the questions together, which he has, I think this is sufficient. Unless/until heap automata become a revolutionary new concept, it's a good idea to keep the tags as general as possible, so no [heap-automata] tag. Tags such as [series](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/series) etc do not make sense in isolation, outside of the specific question, so I don't see how they will be useful.

Comment: I agree. I edited the corresponding questions so their relationship is clear(er) easily navigatable.

Answer (score 0):

Since the concept of heap automata isn't really canonical, I'd be wary of introducing one just for this example. I mean, that seems even more problematic than adding a separate tag for each algorithm or data structure.

Perhaps what would be more appropriate would be a [series](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/series), [series-of-questions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/series-of-questions), or [follow-up](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/follow-up) tag, for the more general case of somebody asking a question, getting an answer, and asking a closely-related question. This can happen pretty generally, and would probably make more clear the fact that the discussion is carried over from another question (which a plethora of specific tags might not make clear).

Comment: I agree with paragraph 1, but not with paragraph 2. Such a tag would be overly general and say nothing about the tagged questions content.

Answer (score -2):

I was about to ask a related question:

Shouldn't this series of question appear as a single community-wiki thread?

Comment: Why????????????

Comment: because it allows to come up with other properties, jointly proven by many people. Eventually, it organizes this entire subject into one very informative thread.

Comment: @RanG.: I'd rather we collaborated to put some summary article on arXiv or something (once we have covered all elementary properties).

Comment: @Raphael it all depends on some "pumping lemma" equivalent we are yet to find